# Adafruit motor hat python3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Iv written a script that uses the adafruit motor hat library to control motors when it recives 433MHz ex transmitted codes! Very short range at the moment however this is the best way for my project!

The problem is the 433MHz rx/tx library is python3 and won't work on python2

And the adafruit_motor_hat_library is pyrhon2 and wont work on pyrhon3?

As I need both of these to work in the same scrip how can I go about this?

Also if I try and run from command line it won't work, (if I python3.scrip.py it brings up error with adafruit motor hat, if I python.script.py it brings up error on 433MHz?

If anybody needs my full scrip I can copy and past it here but as the problem doesn't seem to be with the actual scrip it seemed pretty pointless! But if you need it I can provide it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save time, I would convert the **smaller of the two libraries** you mention to the other version.  If they're about the same size, I'd convert the 2.x library to 3.    The motor hat library is only ~350 lines of code, much of which will not change in conversion to 3.x.  Would be a good self-teaching exercise...

Comment: I have tried using 2to3 But and it seamed to run ok but I couldn't find a new file? Does 2to3 actually creat a new file or does it just convert to old file?

Comment: Also what exact file do I need to use 2to3 on? Have I just converted a file I didn't need to?

Comment: @GeorgeDurell  I didn't suggest any tool.  In your shoes I'd just sit down and convert 2.x to 3.6 or whatever, as you'd learn a lot by doing that and have no questions about how the hat library works.  Great way to learn.

Comment: This may sound a stupid question but you obviously mean actually manually go through the library file and changing the python2 syntax to pyrhon3 syntax? TBH Iv only been using python for less than a year but have already started realising what works in one and not the other, so il give it a go, however this may make more stack questions! Thanks for your help!! And il Probly be back here when I hit a wall with my python knowledge

Comment: @GeorgeDurell Excellent! In the meantime, you can Accept my answer and I'll be here to answer.  I routinely look for questions like yours.

Comment: Iv accepted however, I haven't even started going through th library yet! But il keep you posted, if I manage to make it work I'll post new library on GitHub as I think it will be useful for others

Comment: Just to kept you posted, Iv been through the libraries and successfully modified it to work with python3. Not entirely sure if I did it the correct way but it works for my project, and I can now control the motor hat on a piZero from my pi3, thanks for the encouragement to try myself!